# What is the best way to store and use big JSON data?

Tags: linux, windows, mysql, database, mongodb

I have downloaded a [bibliographic corpus](https://github.com/allenai/s2orc) that consists of 10,000 zipped JSON files with the total size of ~200GB (zipped, ~800GB unzip)

I have no experience in dealing with this amount of data, and I don't own powerful clusters. All I have is a PC with i7-8700K, 64GB RAM, GTX1080Ti graphic card, and 10TB storage.

There are about 81 million publications in this dataset. I want to efficiently find out the citation relationship among them (reference IDs are given as a field of each publication), filtering by some condition (e.g. publication year) is also needed to perform my analysis.

So I am wondering whether my computer is capable of performing analysis on this dataset or not, and what is the best practice to do this job. Is it a good idea if I parse those JSON files and store them in a database like MySQL or MongoDB (some publications have a large full-text field)?

Comment: Are you using Python or what? In any case, I've not tried handling so much data either but maybe [try this](https://mysqlserverteam.com/import-json-to-mysql-made-easy-with-the-mysql-shell/) and see if it works?

Comment: @BrianZ Thanks, but I don't think MySQL is a good idea as the size of data will further increase and the queries take a long time to perform on HDDs.

Comment: Putting the data in a DB (MySQL or else) is a good idea. Don't under-estimate the power of a relational database. You can leave the text outside the DB if that worries you (but it shouldn't). Your main problem is determining the data layout (tables, indexes...) for best performance. and given the size of the DB, have an adequate strategy for its backup. You may also need more RAM than what you currently have.